# Screen resolution twice as wide

Tags: lubuntu, screen, display-resolution, xrandr

I'm trying to install Lubuntu on a large touch screen with built in PC. Installation goes successfully and it boots up just fine, but it seems that I only see the "wrong" half of the screen.

The screen has a resolution of 1920 x 1080, but running xrandr tells me that current is 3840 x 1080.

I cannot see lxpanel or other stuff, just right click and get to terminal. Other stuff like system settings is "on the left"

I've tried xrandr -s 1920x1080, but the screen then turns blank.

Any ideas how to fix the resolution?

**Here's xrandr output.**

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 519mm x 324mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.96    59.93
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88
   1600x1024     60.17
   1400x1050     59.98
   1600x900      59.95    59.82
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.89
   1400x900      59.96    59.88
   1280x960      60.00
   1440x810      59.97
   1368x768      59.88    59.85
   1360x768      59.80    59.96
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91
   1152x864      60.00
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74
   1024x768      60.04    60.00
   960x720       60.00
   928x696       60.05
   896x672       60.01
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82
   960x600       59.93    60.00
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25
   840x525       60.01    59.88
   864x486       59.92    59.57
   800x512       60.17
   700x525       59.98
   800x450       59.95    59.82
   640x512       60.02
   720x450       59.89
   700x450       59.96    59.88
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x405       59.51    58.99
   684x384       59.88    59.85
   680x384       59.80    59.96
   640x400       59.88    59.98
   576x432       60.06
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32
   512x384       60.00
   512x288       60.00    59.92
   480x270       59.63    59.82
   400x300       60.32    56.34
   432x243       59.92    59.57
   320x240       60.05
   360x202       59.51    59.13
   320x180       59.84    59.32
HDMI-1 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 760mm x 450mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  50.00    59.94    30.00    25.00    24.00    29.97    23.98
   1920x1080i    60.00    50.00    59.94
   1600x1200     60.00
   1680x1050     61.00
   1280x1024     60.02
   1440x900      59.90
   1280x800      61.01
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94
   1440x576      50.00
   1024x768      60.00
   1440x480      60.00    59.94
   800x600       60.32
   720x576       50.00
   720x480       60.00    59.94
   640x480       60.00    59.94
   720x400       87.85    70.08
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Comment: The resolution (3840 x 1080) you see is because your machine detects 2 monitors (2x1920x1080), is there another monitor attached? one on the display port and another on the HDMI?

Comment: There isn't another monitor as far as I know

Comment: You can always try to disable one monitor, something like `xrandr --output eDP-1 --primary --auto --output HDMI-1 --off` or shutting down the other monitor `xrandr --output HDMI-1 --primary --auto --output eDP-1 --off`

Answer (score 0):

Solved! (the strange way)...

I installed teamviewer through command line and was then able to get to system settings